# How to add discount price in the reports admin grid

Tags: magento2

I have created report admin grid fetch the collection of catalog product. This thing is done . But I need to add discount price grid
 We need to get final price of the product and discount the amount with the final price and display the result in the admin grid under the reports

Answer (score 0):

I see there some Problems to get a correct final price.

- Taxes can be different by customer and country or website
- incl.Tax or excluded Taxes
- price and special price can be different on every store view
- in Magento, we also tier price that change price based on the amount
- cart price rules and Catalog Price Rules etc...

This function 
`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addPriceData`
allows to get the price information based on `customerGroupId` and a `websiteId`.

The price filter in Magento 2.3.3 is a good reference how to add almost all price
information.

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\ProductPriceFilter::apply`

But there many cases where you don't get the correct price!

Best regards,

Lars